# How to send logcat by curl POST command

Tags: android, shell, curl, adb, logcat

Need to send by shellscript every new string in Android logcat by curl POST command to server. Connected to Android by ADB.
I was trying this things:

```
#logcat com.mm.en:I -e "chat"| tee /sdcard/Pictures/out.txt
```

It makes a file, and write every new string to it.
Next i was trying:

```
#curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://nnnn.ru/test/testprint.php -G -d '{"id":"IDVALUE","name":"Mike"}'
```

It is also work.
But when i trying to combine it by guide, it doesnt work:

```
#logcat com.mm.en:I -e "chat"| curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://nnnn.ru/test/testprint.php -d @-
```

Where i`m wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify what is actually happening in "logcat ... | curl ..."? Nothing is sent? What happens if you replace the logcat with "echo 'trial'? Could be that curl is waiting for the end of the input?

Comment: Yes, in construction above nothing is sent.
Now u use this:
<code>curl -X POST http://nnnn.ru/test/testprint.php -F "$(logcat com.mm.en:I -e "chat" -v raw)"<code>
It send what i need, but only when i stop execution. Does not send every line separated "on-line"